# Converting a DataFrame into a New Table using a Key-Value as the Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to take a large table of stock data in a time series format and convert it to a DataFrame that's indexed by a combination of the ticker and date.

```
data = [['MSFT', 10,9,4,3.5,2.2], ['AAPL', 14,13.1,12.2,14.5,14.6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Ticker', '12/31/2021','11/30/2021','10/31/2021','9/30/2021','8/31/2021'])
```

So it would look more like this below:

```
data2 = [['MSFT_12/31/2021',10], ['MSFT_11/30/2021',9.0], ['MSFT_10/31/2021',4.0], ['AAPL_12/31/2021',14],['AAPL_8/31/2021',14.6]]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Key', 'Value'])
```

```
| Key            | Value |
|MSFT_12/31/2021 |  10.0 |
|MSFT_11/30/2021 |  9.0  |
|MSFT_10/31/2021 |  4.0  |
|AAPL_12/31/2021 |  14.0 |
|AAPL_8/31/2021  |  14.6 |
```

Is there a pythonic or easy way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can `melt` to reshape from wide to long, and create a new column by concatenation of Ticker and the reshaped column:

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['Ticker'])
   .assign(Key=lambda d: d['Ticker']+'_'+d['variable'])
   .drop(columns=['Ticker', 'variable'])
)
```

output:

```
   value              Key
0   10.0  MSFT_12/31/2021
1   14.0  AAPL_12/31/2021
2    9.0  MSFT_11/30/2021
3   13.1  AAPL_11/30/2021
4    4.0  MSFT_10/31/2021
5   12.2  AAPL_10/31/2021
6    3.5   MSFT_9/30/2021
7   14.5   AAPL_9/30/2021
8    2.2   MSFT_8/31/2021
9   14.6   AAPL_8/31/2021
```